# Problem with locking

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have a map which is of type Collections.synchronizedMap . The map contains database tables.

Now I have 3 methods and two lock. The first lock around each database table in a map.And second lock around the map. I know its aSynchronised map so I don't need a lock but I need it because of some other reason.

```
       method1()
       {
            calls readlock on a table (first lock)
            try{
                if(certain condition is satisfied)
                {
                call method2
                }
            }finally{
              realease readlock on the table (first lock)
            }
       }
method2(){
       call write lock on the map first (second lock)
       call write on the table now( first lock) 
       try{
          //do stuff
       }finally{
         unlock write lock on table.
          unlock writelock on map.
       }
}

 Method3(Lock){ //This lock is lock on tables ,can be read as well as write,but unlocked now
 grab readlock on map first
 try{
      //do stuff
       Lock.lock() //lock the table lock now
    }finally{
      realease the readlock now on map
 }
```

I am getting a blocked situation when at method1 a readlock happen on tables and then when in method2 after getting a write on map...

Am I doing something wrong somewhere?

Comment: and please edit your question (including title) to remove the SCREAMING part. it's harder to read. might help if you formatted the code properly too.

Comment: R/W locks are reentrant locks.No they are not upgradable.

Comment: Some proper code formatting would make it easier to follow your code.

Comment: ReentrantReadWriteLock is not upgradable, however it doesn't appear this is being done.  I would suggest you have one and only one lock, I can't tell if you have two or three lcoks on each table i.e. are you counting the lock on the synchronizedMap as well.  Perhaps some actual code will help.

Comment: @jmg, Some proper code would make it easier to follow the code. ;)

Comment: So we understand your use case, perhaps you could explain the features you need which `ConcurrentHashMap` does not provide. ;)

Comment: its very complicated can't explain it here....thats why written a psedo code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method 1, you get the readlock on table. In method2, you try to get the writelock on table while its readlock hasn't been released. Thus the program hangs there, waiting all other locks on table to be released. Then a deadlock happens.

Comment: I unlock the readlock prior to calling method2 jus now...jus debugging it now..lets me see...